# C:\Users\Admin>pipenv --python 3.9 "pipenv" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом

Tags: python, pipenv

C:\Users\Admin>pip install pipenv
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: pipenv in c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (2021.5.29)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv-clone>=0.2.5 in c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pipenv) (0.5.6)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=36.2.1 in c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages (from pipenv) (56.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=18.0 in c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pipenv) (21.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pipenv) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from pipenv) (20.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: backports.entry-points-selectable>=1.0.4 in c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: platformdirs<3,>=2 in c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from virtualenv->pipenv) (0.3.2)

здраствуйте помогите пожалуйста  как установить пакет управления виртуальным окружениям пайтон
и как создать среду

а то вилазит код:

C:\Users\Admin>pipenv --python 3.9
"pipenv" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Answer (score 2):

Для начала установим pipenv с помощью pip

```
pip install pipenv
```

После установки создаю папку для вирт.среды примеру 'text' и захожу в неё,после этих действий я указываю версию интерпретатора:

```
pipenv --python 3.9
```

Команда автоматически создаст виртуальное окружение и после можно активировать виртуальное окружение:

```
pipenv shell
```